# Is there any linux server with public ip on the internet?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, internet

Im learning Linux but not always in home.
Is there any Linux server on the internet with ssh and remote terminal enabled for testing and training?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure; it's called Amazon EC2. You can get a free instance for up to a year, and SSH into it from anywhere you please.

Comment: "I want" and "free" should never be in the same sentence. If it has value to you, you should be willing to pay *something* for it.

Comment: It is free. For up to a year. If you're not done learning the basics to run Linux on your home computer after a year, you might need to re-think your strategy

Comment: Don't mean to overly promote my answer, but SDF is free forever, if you can get a referral. Otherwise, it's a one-time payment of $1, which isn't alot to pay for if you're not trying to develop some huge web application. You have two (or maybe even three) whole years before you have to validate though, which as aforementioned, should be more than enough time to learn the basics of a *nix system.

Comment: @CalebXu - for what it's worth I think your answer is far more appropriate for the op's skill level. I had no idea such a thing actually exists, and I urge Ahmad to re-think his acceptance of this answer and try Caleb's first

Answer (score 8):

**There's the SDF Public Access Server (http://sdf.org/?signup) and it is free forever (but they accept and appreciate donations).**. Really easy to sign up (connect, and your account is created within the SSH session). Has some file storage, SSH, `screen`, etc. Even more options are available after a one time donation.

EDIT: The make new user account function is down for maintenance at the moment. Hope it will be back soon.

If you don't like SDF very much, there's a whole list of them at http://shells.red-pill.eu/. The first five are sponsored, but the rest are pretty legit. Note that not all of the shells on that site are Linux; some are also BSD, and some also don't use `bash` by default. The services and rules of each website differ, so look through all the pages before you make a decision.